# react map function array of styles to set as props dosent work

Tags: reactjs, next.js

hay im using next react app and im traying to take array of 9 elemnts and map props to style
but it dosent work

```js
// the array 
 [{ gridarea: `1 / 1 / 2 / 2`} , { gridarea: `1 / 2 / 2 / 3`},{ gridarea: `1 / 3 / 2 / 4`},{ gridarea: `2 / 1 / 3 / 2`},{ gridarea: `2 / 2 / 3 / 3`},{ gridarea: `2 / 3 / 3 / 4`},{ gridarea: `3 / 1 / 4 / 2`},{ gridarea: `3 / 2 / 4 / 3`},{ gridarea: `3 / 3 / 4 / 4`}]
 
 
 // map ansewer from api to elemnts 
 //data is state 
  {data.length !== 0 ? data.map((c , i) => <Card value={c} mystyle={stylearray[i]} key={i}/>) : ""}
```

but inside card component im using

```js
 <div style={props.mystyle}>
        <img src={props.value.path} alt="img"  onError={errorhandle} style={stylephoto}/>
        <p style={textstyle}>{props.value.title}</p> 
    </div>
```

and the props.mystyle dosent work what am i doing wrong thanks you for your help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajep9.png) console.log i did on the props

Comment: where is stylearray array in this code ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your style object, it should be `[{gridArea: '1 / 1 / 2 / 2'}, ...]` or `[{'grid-area': '1 / 1 / 2 / 2'}, ...]` but you are using `gridarea` as css property which is not a valid css property so you couldn't see it's result on the `Card` component's content.

Also consider that your `Card` components must be placed inside a container with `grid` display.